# How to create a matrix with specific element subscripts and input subscripts into function as arguments

Tags: matrix

I'd like to create a matrix with specific elements subscripts. Matrix is like below.
[image]

This matrix is sized at `M*M` and subscripts are indexed by `(m-n,n)`. And I need to input subscripts into function as arguments.

I got this idea because I know the `List` in Mathematica can operate listablly. But I'm not sure this kind of subscripts is achievable.

Basically speaking, all I need to do is just to input subscripts(i.e.`(m-n,n)`) as arguments and fetch the results(i.e. `Lambda(x,y)`) to save them into this matrix at corresponding position. But how can I assign these specific subscripts to elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
M=3;
Table[Which[
  col<row,0,
  True,Subscript[λ,col-row,row]
],{col,0,M},{row,0,M}]
```

which returns

```
{{Subscript[λ, 0, 0], 0,                  0,                  0},
 {Subscript[λ, 1, 0], Subscript[λ, 0, 1], 0,                  0}, 
 {Subscript[λ, 2, 0], Subscript[λ, 1, 1], Subscript[λ, 0, 2], 0}, 
 {Subscript[λ, 3, 0], Subscript[λ, 2, 1], Subscript[λ, 1, 2], Subscript[λ, 0, 3]}}
```

without more fiddling and time I can't make those subscripts into tiny digits, but it appears to be what you are asking for when I evaluate that in a notebook.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill!

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[array]
array[m_Integer, n_Integer] := 
 Array[If[# < #2, 0, Subscript[λ, # - #2, #2]] &, {m, n}, {0, 0}]


MatrixForm @ array[5, 5]
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ MatrixForm@array[5, 5]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \lambda _{0,0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \lambda _{1,0} & \lambda _{0,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \lambda _{2,0} & \lambda _{1,1} & \lambda _{0,2} & 0 & 0 \\
 \lambda _{3,0} & \lambda _{2,1} & \lambda _{1,2} & \lambda _{0,3} & 0 \\
 \lambda _{4,0} & \lambda _{3,1} & \lambda _{2,2} & \lambda _{1,3} & \lambda _{0,4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to do with `SparseArray`:

```
Normal @ SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j :> Subscript[λ, i - j, j - 1]}, {5, 5}]
```